# How to Handle Errors in response object

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, api, error-handling

In application when logging with wrong username or password it send me an error object in response.

```
POST https://abcdserver.zxcv.com/abcdserver/connect/token 400 (Bad Request)
Error performing password flow 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", url: "https://abcdserver.zxcv.com/abcdserver/connect/token", ok: false, …}
```

How to handle those errors. Here is my code

login.component.ts

```
jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
  this.authService.loginOrg(this.userCredential.email, this.userCredential.password).then((resp) => {
    let token = resp['access_token'];
    if (token === null) {
      this.invalidLogin = true;
    }
    let decodedToken = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);
    this.UserId = decodedToken.userid;
  }, (reason) => {
    this.invalidLogin = true;
  });
```

authservice.component.ts

```
import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';    
public loginOrg(userName: string, password: string) {
        return this.oAuthService.fetchTokenUsingPasswordFlow(userName, password);
    }
```

Comment: what you want to achieve ? as if error coming you want to show in your application as a toast or alertbox or ignore it ?

Comment: Please include the code where you make the request

Comment: I am handling by giving the message in UI if wrong credentials are given. However, when it comes to production I don't want to see those console errors

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options: 
1) Implement the ErrorHandler (https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler) to handle all the errors generated in your app, OR 
2) handle each error in your http call like this: 
        this.getMEthod().subscribe(resp =>{ your logic here}, error =>{ your logic here})